# Dovecot: no auth attempts - from local IP

Tags: dovecot, imap

Please note, this is not like the other question asked about the same topic (wrong SSL setup, whatever)! My mail setup works fine, IMAP / POP3 login and smtp is just working.
But I have some log entries I do not understand.

The machine has two interfaces.
eth0 -> 172.16.5.12 (an internal IP)
eth1 -> public IP address

```
dovecot: auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=x)  
dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=172.16.5.12, lip=172.16.5.12, TLS, session=<xxxasd>
```

Postfix uses Dovecot as auth backend (if this is important). I do not perform any other IMAP login from the machine itself.
What I wonder is, why it uses the IP 172.16.5.12 and not even 127.0.0.1 if there would be any attemp.

What I tried:
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 143 -j DROP
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j DROP

Log entries are still there. If any config snippet is needed to debug what this is, please let me know!

--

I have another mailserver with nearly similar setup, on this server the rip and lip in the maillog is the public IP address from eth1.

Comment: can it be monitoring service which try to connect ? Then it may don't have anything to do with postfix... BTW, to block on loopback, you must use -i lo in your iptables rules, not eth0

Comment: Could be, I will check it. Loopback is on lo, eth0 is not loopback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection was from the monitoring, there was one checking the port if open and one which validated the SSL certificate. Thanks @Dom